# Scalar subquery produced more than one element SQL, using SUM OVER PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cumulative-sum

I am trying to query the running total of rains in 3 cities between exact years, but names are inconsistent in the original data and is not possible to clean from datasource. I have tried the following code, but keep getting the response "Scalar subquery produced more than one element".

```
  SELECT    
  Year,
  Place,
  TotalRain,
  FROM(SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as Year,
        REPLACE(location_name,(
               SELECT location_name FROM data.rain.pakistan
               WHERE LOWER (location_name) LIKE LOWER ('%lahore%')
         ),'Lahore'),
         REPLACE(location_name,(
               SELECT location_name FROM data.rain.pakistan
               WHERE LOWER (location_name) LIKE LOWER ('%karachi%')
         ),'Karachi'),
         REPLACE(location_name,(
               SELECT location_name FROM data.rain.pakistan
               WHERE LOWER (location_name) LIKE LOWER ('%islamabad%')
         ),'Islamabad'),
      
        location_name AS Place,
        SUM(mm_rain) OVER (PARTITION BY location_name ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)) AS TotalRain
        FROM 
        data.rain.pakistan
  )  WHERE Place IN ('Lahore', 'Karachi', 'Islamabad')
  AND Year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2021                                                          
      GROUP BY Year, Place ,TotalRain             
       ORDER BY Year, Place
```

Please tell me if you know any solution!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and the goal is to have a running sum over the years for a location, also assuming the input table is flat, the query below should work:

```
SELECT    
  Year,
  Place,
  SUM(mm_rain) OVER (PARTITION BY Place ORDER BY Year) AS TotalRain
  FROM(
    SELECT 
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as Year,
        case 
          when lower(location_name) like '%lahore%' then 'Lahore'
          when lower(location_name) like '%karachi%' then 'Karachi'
          when lower(location_name) like '%islamabad%' then 'Islamabad'
        else location_name end as Place,
        mm_rain
      FROM input
  )  
WHERE Place IN ('Lahore', 'Karachi', 'Islamabad')
  AND Year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2021                                                          
GROUP BY Year, Place, mm_rain
ORDER BY Year, Place
```

I don't think subqueries are mandatory, but it depends on the input table.

Comment: Thanks Xavier, I came to the same resolution just some minutes ago. Its the simpler and cleaner way